# Ionic input hiding by itself while typing email address

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid

I have tried to implement the page which requires an email address to reset the password. But I'm having some issue in the ionic input. The Ionic input line hides automatically in the middle while typing the email address

How can I solve this? I don't know where's the issue is from? Either with my HTML or CSS or TS.

My code:

forgotpwd.html:

```
<ion-content class="ioncontent" no-bounce padding>
    <div>
        <div text-center fixed-content>
            <div class="login-logo-container">
                <img src="assets/imgs/login_logo.png" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="div-card" fixed-content>
            <label class="labelstyle"> We just need your registered email id to send <br /> your password reset instructions </label>
            <form [formGroup]="forgotpasswordform">
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-icon name="md-mail"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label color="primary" floating>Email Address</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="vm.emailAddress" formControlName="emailAddress" name="emailAddress"
                                   (keyup)="moveFocus($event,password, true)"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                    <div class="error-message" style="margin-left: 15px" *ngIf="forgotpasswordform.controls.emailAddress.errors && (forgotpasswordform.controls.emailAddress.dirty || forgotpasswordform.controls.emailAddress.touched)">
                        <span *ngIf="forgotpasswordform.controls.emailAddress.errors?.required">Email address is required</span>
                        <span *ngIf="forgotpasswordform.controls.emailAddress.errors?.email">Email address is invalid</span>
                    </div>
                </ion-row>
                <div class="full-width pull-right">
                    <button ion-button icon-end name="submitbutton" type="button" (click)="submitforget()" class="button" color="purple">
                        Submit
                        <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button ion-button icon-end name="cancelbutton" type="button" (click)="cancel()" class="button" color="purple">
                        Cancel
                        <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

My CSS:

```
page-forgotpassword {

    .full-width {
        width: 100%;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 8%;
    }

    .div-card {
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        height: 80% !important;
        margin-top: -100% !important;
    }

    .ioncontent {
        background-image: url('../assets/imgs/login_background.jpg');
        // background-image: url('../assets/imgs/login_logo.png');
        background-size: cover;
        overflow: scroll !important;
    }
   .labelstyle{
       color: white;
   }

    .error-message {
        padding-top: 0px !important;
        text-align: left !important;
    }

    .item-inner, ion-item {
        border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        outline: none !important;
    }

    ion-row {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    ion-item {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    ion-input {
        color: #bdcde7 !important;
    }
}


/*.email {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00b1ff;
}

.icon-inputs {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    min-width: 0 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    color: #00b1ff;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: -9px !important;
    zoom: 0.8;
}


.item-inner, ion-item {
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
}

.icon-ends-fget-cancel {
    background-color: #00b1ff;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    margin-left: 88%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon-end-check-fgetsubmit {
    background-color: #00b1ff;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    vertical-align: end;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 65%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.submit-button-checkmark-icon-alignment {
    vertical-align: right;
}*/
```

My forgotpwd.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ForgotPassword } from '../../models/forgotpassword';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthenticationService } from "../../services/authentication.service";
import { MessageService } from "../../services/message.service";
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

/**
 * Generated class for the ForgotpasswordPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-forgotpassword',
    templateUrl: 'forgotpassword.html',
})
export class ForgotpasswordPage {
    vm: ForgotPassword;
    emailpattern: string = "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$";
    forgotpasswordform: FormGroup;
    forgotpasswordservice: AuthenticationService;
    isPasswordReset: boolean = false;
    statusMessage: string;
    isEmailExist: boolean;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform, public navParams: NavParams,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private messageService: MessageService
    ) {
        this.vm = new ForgotPassword();
        this.isPasswordReset = false;
        this.statusMessage = '';
        platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => this.myHandlerFunction());
    }

    moveFocus(event, nextElement, isLastControl) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            if (isLastControl && isLastControl === false)
                nextElement.setFocus();
            else if (isLastControl && isLastControl === true)
                this.submitforget();
        }
    }

    myHandlerFunction() {
        this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initializeValidators();
    }

    initializeValidators() {
        this.forgotpasswordform = new FormGroup({
            emailAddress: new FormControl('',
                [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.email
                ]),
        });
    }

    cancel() {
        this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
    }

    submitforget() {
        if (this.forgotpasswordform.valid) {
            this.authenticationService.forgotpassword(this.vm.emailAddress).subscribe((data) => {
                this.isPasswordReset = true;
                this.isEmailExist = data !== 'EmailNotExist';
                if (data === 'EmailNotExist') {
                    this.messageService.alert('This email address does not exist on our system please click here to register');
                } else {
                    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
                    this.messageService.alert('Link to reset the password had been sent to the registered email address');
                }

            });
        } else {
            this.validateAllFormFields(this.forgotpasswordform);
        }
    }
    validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
        Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
            const control = formGroup.get(field);
            if (control instanceof FormControl) {
                control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
            } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
                this.validateAllFormFields(control);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is a scenario image:

[image: Hidden]

It's behaving in such a way that it automatically appearing and disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ionic native keyboard  [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/)

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { }

...

this.keyboard.show();

// this.keyboard.close();
```

Comment: Can you provide me exact solution? Since I am new to ionic., I don't have any prior knolwedge about it